# What environment makes Node.js the happiest?

Tags: node.js, operating-system

Can anyone tell me what OS [Ryan Dahl](http://tinyclouds.org/) uses as his main? I've seen him using a Mac in his demos but I also heard him say Mac is sh*t.

I'm curious what OS he, as the creator of Node.js, uses since that is likely the easiest to use for Node.js development.

And just in case no one knows, perhaps just tell me what OS is recommended for Node.js development.

Comment: Ryan also says JavaScript is *** and http is ***.  I wouldn't read too much into it.

Comment: Some of the information on windows here is outdated. Windows installation is a piece of cake now (.msi installer). Alternatively, you can develop in Cloud9 on windows as easily as you could on any other platform.

Comment: Agreed - I wouldn't host it on Windows, but with their Azure installer and tutorials, MS has done a good job of getting the node-curious coding quickly.  Even if you won't use A$ure, the cloud storage emulator is a nice extra to play with.

Comment: He sure might be using SmartOS on production. SmartOS is proprietory OS of Joyent, those are the people who put money into building nodejs.

Comment: @JuzerAli SmartOS is forked from Solaris. So I guess the base OS for Node.js production OS should be Solaris?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> I'm curious what OS he, as the creator
>   of Node.js, uses since that is likely
>   the easiest to use for Node.js
>   development.

OS he uses is likely to be the best for him and his preference. You shouldn't be influenced by this because you may find other systems/IDEs/editors much better suited for you and your workflow compared to what Ryan Dahl is using. For example Ryan is often using Vi (or Vim?) editor which is really powerful tool, but too "hardcore" for many (or I would say majority of) developers.

> tell me what OS is recommended for
>   Node.js development

Linux based systems (because you rather shouldn't vary too much from targeted production system - the least is the difference the less problems you may encounter). You can use any kind of operating system for development and still have all the codez located on target machine where you are running node.js programs. For example on Windows you can use WinSCP as file manager, Notepad++ as code editor and putty for remote connection to your Linux system.

Answer (score 15):

Windows is a perfectly fine system to both develop node applications as well as to deploy them. [Microsoft partnered with Joyent](http://blog.nodejs.org/2011/06/23/porting-node-to-windows-with-microsoft%E2%80%99s-help/) to help them port the code and the [Windows Azure](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/nodejs/) cloud hosting environment supports Node.js now. All of the npm packages I have used have had not problems running on Windows.

All of the node apps I have written run just as well on my Windows laptop, Macbook Air, and on Cloud9 without any problems. At this point, just pick whatever environment you are most comfortable working in!

Comment: That's distinct from cygwin or msys though, which seems to be what he was referring to by 'platform.'

Comment: Just wanted to chime in here. Using Git Bash @ http://git-scm.com/downloads in Windows I find I do most everything at least as well as when I work on my Mac. My biggest complaint is that Foreman for heroku I was unable to get working in Windows. I use Linux VM for my django dev.. Everything else is fine on windows!

Comment: I develop in Linux with node and Webstorm as IDE and the best part is the deployment process since I'm using Linux servers. Tried a couple of times with Mac OS but I just don't feel confortable at all. Haven't tried yet on windows.

Comment: The deployment process is likely very similar to what you would do on OSX or Windows. For most of my projects I just use Git or Github deployment and the steps are exactly the same regardless of OS.

Comment: node-gyp on windows is a sad experience.

Comment: node-gyp is a pretty sad experience pretty much everywhere I've encountered it.

Answer (score 14):

Looking at node's manual, it seems like Unix-based environments are what's best for node. This includes linux, and mac, which had came a long way and is in the process of pampering the crap out of traditional terminal hardcores with stuff like homebrew.

Windows on the other hand is the worst environment for node. Not only there's very little information on how to deploy one on a windows machine, most of the other related technologies that make node such a happy place to work in have quirky windows implementation, if any at all.

In short, there's a far larger community on Unix-based system for node than windows, and considering the amount of tutorials online, it's better that you stick to a Unix based platform.

Comment: Mac is definitely not linux based. It's much better to say they are both Unix based.

Comment: Thanks rjmunro. You're right, Unix based.

Comment: Please provide a link to the part of the manual you have read. Thnx.

Comment: This answer is 2 years old. Much has changed since. :)

Answer (score 4):

I don't know what Ryan's OS of choice is, as my fellow posters i'd put my bet on a Linux-based system using vi(m) as the editor.

If you want to stick to a windows platform, try using [VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org) as a virtualization software. I use a virtual debian system as my node.js development environment, mounting my Windows directories using VBOX's shared folder functionality. All my git/npm/testing related stuff is done directly on the virtual machine, haven't had any problems so far.

As my code editors, i use [Aptana Studio 3](http://www.aptana.com/products/studio3) (Eclipse-based) and [Cloud9](http://cloud9ide.com/).

Using Windows and MINGW is not really recommended, since node.js will probably never really be stable on that platform.

Helpful readups for VirtualBox/Debian:

- [Installing Guest Additions on Debian](http://virtualboxes.org/doc/installing-guest-additions-on-debian/)